# Mariadb -> connect engine -> unixodbc -> firebird

Tags: firebird, mariadb, unixodbc

I like to use connect engine of mariadb to connect to a firebird database via ODBC on a server which is running on Centos 7.

I have already established a connection to sqlserver. The odbc-test to the firebird-database with isql works as well.

This is my create-statement:

```
CREATE TABLE con.test_table_apys
ENGINE=CONNECT
TABLE_TYPE=ODBC
TABNAME='wsk_lager_st'
CONNECTION='DSN=apys;UID=SYSDBA;PWD=myownpassword';
```

After sending the statement to the server I got this error message:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
```

This is the content of odbc.ini

```
[apys]
Description     = Firebird
Driver          = Firebird
Dbname          = apysdbserver/3051:vm_apys_ori205
Role            =
CharacterSet    = WIN1252
ReadOnly        = No
NoWait          = No
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Now it works. The modifications are:

I have put username and password in odbc.ini

```
[apys]
Description     = Firebird
Driver          = Firebird
Dbname          = apysdbserver/3051:vm_apys_ori205
Role            =
CharacterSet    = WIN1252
ReadOnly        = No
NoWait          = No
User            = SYSDBA
Password        = myownpassword
```

removed user and password from create-statement

```
CREATE TABLE con.test_table_apys
ENGINE=CONNECT
TABLE_TYPE=ODBC
TABNAME='wsk_lager_st'
CONNECTION='DSN=apys';
```

and defined the columns

```
CREATE TABLE con.test_table_apys (
ID INT,
some_text VARCHAR(100)
)
ENGINE=CONNECT
TABLE_TYPE=ODBC
TABNAME='wsk_lager_st'
CONNECTION='DSN=apys';
```